# VBScript Environment variables

Tags: vbscript, environment-variables

I have a question regarding how I should go about fixing an error that I am seeing when running my script. I am pretty sure it has to do with the way in which I am using the %COMPUTERNAME% environment variable.

What my script does is it zips up some files locally, then copies them using robocopy to a mounted or shared drive, then checks to see if the file sizes are the same, and if they are then it deletes the files on the original computer. If any step in the process produces an error it exits the script.

Now the script works perfectly fine if I do not add in the "%COMPUTERNAME%" to the final destination path. (Where the zipped files will eventually be) I need the zipped files to be placed into their own folders with the name of the host from which it originated, because this script will be run on many different machines all going to the same location.

So basically it needs to look something like this:

E:\LocalHostName\TestZip.zip

Now the script will build the folder just fine when the zipped files are being copied over, the problem occurs once the file size check starts. I am getting the error of "File not found" for the line "FileToBeCompared2". I understand why the error is being produced, because it is not recogizing the %COMPUTERNAME% environment variable, but I do not know how to go about addressing this issue.

I am also going to try to add in some functionality where if an error occurs a text file with something like "An error occured during the script" is produced in the output folder.

Thank you for all your help in advance. The script is found below:

```
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'This script is used to zip files locally, copy them to a new location, verify that the
'files were copied correctly, and then delete the files from the original source.
'In it's current state it is being used as a means to zip event files and move them
'to a central location.

'Run with administrator priveleges.

'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Option Explicit

Dim sDirectoryPath, sLocalDestinationPath, sFinalDestinationPath, sOutputFilename, Shell, sFileExt, sFilePrefix

Set Shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

'Specify Directory Path where files to be zipped are located
'Specify local destination for zipped files
'Specify final destination path for zippped files
'Specify file extension name to look for
'Specify prefix of filename to look for

sDirectoryPath = "C:\Testscripts\"
sLocalDestinationPath = "C:\ScriptOutput\"
sFinalDestinationPath = "E:\CopyTestFolder\" & sOutputFilename & "\" 
sFileExt = ".evtx"
sFilePrefix = "Archive*"
sOutputFilename = shell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%COMPUTERNAME%") 'Environment variables needed for grabbing hostname

Dim ZipCommand, RobocopyCommand, RunCommand, filesys, filetext
Dim d : d = Date() 
Dim dateStr : dateStr = Year(d) & "-" & Right("00" & Month(d), 2) & "-" & Right("00" &     Day(d), 2) 'Date String
Dim t : t = Time()
Dim timeStr: timeStr = Hour(t) & "-" & Right("00" & Minute(t), 2) & "-" & Right("00" & Second(t), 2) 'Time String
Dim FullFileName

FullFileName = sOutputFilename & "-" & dateStr & "-" & timeStr & ".zip "

'Following command runs 7-zip and grabs the files to be zipped from your set sDirectoryPath, zips them into set sLocalDestinationPath
'and names the file with the localhost name and date/time

ZipCommand = """C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe"" a " & sLocalDestinationPath & FullFileName & sDirectoryPath & sFilePrefix & sFileExt

RunCommand = Shell.Run(ZipCommand,0,true)

if err.Number <> 0 then
    WScript.Echo "An error has occurred during the zip process, re-run Script."     WScript.Quit
end if

Wscript.Sleep 2000

'The following command creates a folder named after the host computer where the files are being copied from 

Dim newfolder, newfolderpath, filesys2

newfolderpath = "E:\CopyTestFolder\" & sOutputFilename & "\"
set filesys2 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If Not filesys2.FolderExists(newfolderpath) Then
    Set newfolder = filesys2.CreateFolder(newfolderpath)
End If

'Following command runs Robocopy from command line, moves files from your set sLocalDestinationPath to your set sFinalDestinationPath       

WScript.Echo "Robocopy.exe " & sLocalDestinationPath & " " & sFinalDestinationPath  
RobocopyCommand = "Robocopy.exe " & sLocalDestinationPath & " " & sFinalDestinationPath 
RunCommand = Shell.Run(RobocopyCommand,0,true)

if err.Number <> 0 then
    WScript.Echo "An error has occured copying the files, re-run Script."
    WScript.Quit
end if

Dim fso, FileToBeCompared1, FileToBeCompared2

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Setting the Local file to be compared
Set FileToBeCompared1 = fso.GetFile(sLocalDestinationPath & FullFileName) 
WScript.echo sFinalDestinationPath & FullFileName

'Setting the file copied to final destination to be compared
Set FileToBeCompared2 = fso.GetFile(sFinalDestinationPath & FullFileName)       

If FileToBeCompared1.size = FileToBeCompared2.size then
    fso.DeleteFile("C:\Testscripts\Archive*.evtx") 'This will be the path where events are being Archived to. (Non restricted path)
    fso.DeleteFolder("C:\ScriptOutput") 'This deletes the archive folder that 7-zip builds each time this script is run
else
    WScript.Echo "File sizes do not match, File was not fully copied, Re run script."   
    WScript.Quit
end if
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `fso.GetFile()` will not automatically expand `%COMPUTERNAME%`, modify `sFinalDestinationPath` to use `sOutputFilename` like this:

```
sOutputFilename = shell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%COMPUTERNAME%")
sFinalDestinationPath = "E:\CopyTestFolder\" & sOutputFilename & "\"
```

Comment: Will try this in a bit once I get back to my comp. Thank you for your help!

Comment: This does make it not produce the error but the only problem now is that it does not produce a folder with the localhost name in "CopyTestFolder" it just places the zipped file in there.

Comment: Robocopy.exe C:\ScriptOutput\ E:\CopyTestFolder\\

Comment: So it's not reading the rest of the copy command for some reason

Comment: I think something is wrong with the amount of quotes I have on this,
sFinalDestinationPath = "E:\CopyTestFolder\ " & sOutputFilename & "\"

Comment: Yea, the echo for robocopy and the echo for the file size compare both are having teh same problem, they aren't recognizing sOutputFilename and are just throwing a dbl slash \\

Comment: I don't think there are too many quotes.  Maybe `sOutputFilename` is empty?

Comment: Hmmm.. yes, I hadn't thought of that honestly. BEfore when i was just using %COMPUTERNAME% it was automatically building the folder with the host name and placing the zip inside of it, now it is not. So I guess that I need to have it make the folder inside copytestfolder so that the script will recognize the path.

Comment: Okay, now I have the folder being made before the copy tries to take place at least. It still is just outputting the file into E:\CopyTestFolder instead of E:\CopyTestFolder\hostname though

Comment: Robocopy should create the destination folder if it doesn't exist.  It might help to track down the problem if you update your question to show the changes you've made to the code so far.

Comment: updated, let me know if anything is confusing or needs to be explained.

Comment: `sOutputFilename` needs to be defined before `sFinalDestinationPath`.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! I do not know how I had not thought of that yet, but thank you so much.