# How to get %username% in VBScript?

Tags: windows, networking, vbscript

I am trying to hide network path of shared folders from domain users. (Windows Server 2012) I have found this script while searching for network drive labeling:

```
Option Explicit
Dim objNetwork, strDrive, objShell, objUNC
Dim strRemotePath, strDriveLetter, strNewName

strDriveLetter = "H:"
strRemotePath = "\\servername\sharedfoldername$\"
strNewName = "Save Your Files Here"

'Section to map the network drive
Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
objNetwork.MapNetworkDrive strDriveLetter, strRemotePath

'Section which actually (re)names the Mapped Drive
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
objShell.NameSpace(strDriveLetter).Self.Name = strNewName

WScript.Echo "Check : "& strDriveLetter & " for " & strNewName
WScript.Quit
```

My network path will be like below:

```
strRemotePath = "\\servername\sharedfoldername1$\%username%"
strRemotePath = "\\servername\sharedfoldername2$\%username%"
strRemotePath = "\\servername\sharedfoldername5$\%username%"
strRemotePath = "\\servername\sharedfoldernameNNN$\%username%"
```

When I insert `%username%`, the script does not run.

Kindly guide me how to modify this script that will run as per my requirements.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I pick up environment variables in vbscript WSH script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/904739/can-i-pick-up-environment-variables-in-vbscript-wsh-script)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBScript Environment variables](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11620970/692942)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [expand environment variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy8116cf.aspx) in your path string:

```
strRemotePath = "\\servername\sharedfoldername1$\%username%"

Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.Echo sh.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(strRemotePath)
```

or you can [build the path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0z2z1zt.aspx) from the share and the [`UserName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3fxhka75.aspx) property of the [`WshNetwork`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6wt333f.aspx) that you already have:

```
share = "\\servername\sharedfoldername1$"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
WScript.Echo fso.BuildPath(share, objNetwork.UserName)
```